# Which are the pros and cons of using auto in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

A collegue said to me that he doesn't see the benefits of using `auto` in C++11, because it can create troubles with the types of the variables.

What do you guys think?

Which are for you the benefits and disadvantage of using `auto` in your code?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052786/reasons-to-use-the-auto-keyword-in-c11/32052997

Comment: Opinion: You should know what type your variables are - do it the old, clear and explicit way

Comment: That is discussed so often that there is no need to do it here again. There are also in SO some discussions but more are in the web. I will not reference on them, because they are already referenced in the SO questions which you wrote your duplicate on.

Comment: You may want to read http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/13/gotw-93-solution-auto-variables-part-2/ and http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/

Comment: I personally prefer typing `auto` instead of something ludicrously long like `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point` :) If I would have to bring up actual technical reasons, I would say go watch [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnqTKD8uD64&feature=youtu.be&t=1705)

Comment: Don't listen to Herb. Your colleague is right.